# Is it possible to get GCC 3.4.6 to compile UTF-8 with BOM source files?

Tags: c++, linux

I had an c++ application which uses unicode string inside it, I had compiled the solution
---- using Visual Studio 2012. 
------Window 7

The file is saved in utf-8 with BOM(byte order marker). When I run the same file in linux, I got the following errors:-
 error: stray '\239' in program
 1: error: stray '\187' in program
 1: error: stray '\191' in program

I found that gcc won't support BOM in the c++ file.If I remove the BOM from the file error get resolved. Is there a way by which I can compile my application containing files saved in utf-8 with BOM ?

One more thing, I am compiling the application in "Red hat enterprise Linux 4 edition" , where GCC version 3.4.6.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks & Regards
 Vikas

Comment: I believe you are going to have a hard time, unless upgrading gcc, I see in gcc 4.1.2 a bug fix for something like that (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33415), it seems that since 4.3, it is mainstream.

Comment: Dear Armel...
Thanks for responding me.Can you please tell me the way to upgrade in red hat enterprise edition 4 ?I try to upgrade 4.1.2 using cd rom of red Hat enterprise 4 , but i was still getting errors. I guess it becaause of the bug in 4.1.2 compiler. Please help me

Comment: Dear Expoerts

which verison of gcc I can use in my Red hat enterprsie edition 4 that can support files having utf8 with BOM(byte order marker). Can anybody please tell me the source from where I can donwload the same and fix my problem.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: unfortunately I am not used to RedHat stuff...

Comment: Dear Experts


Is there any patch created for RedHat Enterprise Edition 4 that solve the bug of GCC for not compling files having UTF8 with byte order marker?

Answer (score 2):

**@gcc:**
You can use

```
-lstdc++
```

as compiler option, to compile utf-8 BOM files

(I'm adding this here, because this thread is a high rated result on google about this topic)